# Crystal Report Syntax for replace string with another string in field table

Tags: sql, string, syntax, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am quite new so I apologize beforehand. I am in Crystal Reports v.11 and I am needing to do a type of string alias. For example: Within table 1 has two field names where I need to convert from 'A' to 'B'.

I've tried several syntax's and none work:

- `ToText({table_name},"A","B")`
- `if {table_name}='A' then 'B' else {table_name}`
- `if {table_name}='A' then 'B' else ""`
- `Replace({table_name},"A","B")`
  *error message "A boolean is required here."

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to change the name of a table or the value that is contained in one of the fields?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
StringVar ReplaceString;

ReplaceString := Replace ({table_Name}, "A", "B");
ReplaceString
```

Now, if you get a boolean error than you need to let us know what type of field you are dealing with.

Comment: `whileprintingrecords` is probably not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a table alias, you need to do so in the Database Expert.  Once there select the desired table, hit `F2`, then modify the name as desired?